# How to change my tree image to the image that I have tapped on the other screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

The main objective that I wanted to achieve was if I tap a specific tree image that is in the tree_design_page, it will automatically change the default tree image in the main_page to the tapped tree image.

I've tried to send the selected tree's index to the main_page but there was an error occurred saying "The named parameter 'index' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument." in the sidebar.dart

These are the main codes that I am working on right now.

## tree_design_page.dart

```
PageView.builder(
          itemCount: treeModelList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => MainPage(index: index),
                        ));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(treeModelList[index].thumbnailUrl),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

## main_page.dart

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({
    super.key,
    //required this.treeModel,
    required this.index,
  });

  //final TreeModel treeModel;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('lib/images/green_meadow.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Background Image
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Image.asset(
                'lib/images/green_meadow.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            // Overlay Image
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              left: 105.7,
              child: /*Image.asset(
                'lib/images/tree_illust.png',
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
              ),*/
                  Image.network(treeModelList[index].thumbnailUrl),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## sidebar.dart

```
class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const SideBar({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SideBar> createState() => _SideBarState();
}

class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar> {
  List<ScreenHiddenDrawer> _pages = [];

  final _baseStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14,
    color: Colors.black,
  );

  final _selectedStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 24,
    color: Colors.white,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pages = [
      //main page
      ScreenHiddenDrawer(
        ItemHiddenMenu(
          name: 'Hello there!',
          baseStyle: _baseStyle,
          selectedStyle: _selectedStyle,
        ),
        MainPage(), //Error message: The named parameter 'index' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument.
      ),

      ...Other pages

      
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HiddenDrawerMenu(
      backgroundColorMenu: const Color.fromRGBO(151, 193, 169, 1),
      screens: _pages,
      initPositionSelected: 0,
      slidePercent: 60,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to look at the repository, here's the link.
https://github.com/loupdaniel/Eco-Tree-Growing

Comment: Keep your View, Controller, and Model separate.  If you have data shared on multiple screens, it belongs in state management somewhere.  I prefer and recommend Riverpod.

Comment: Oh... is this related to state management? I have 0 experience with state management so that's why I haven't come up with that solution :(

Could you please explain how this objective could be achieved with state management?

I would also like to know if it's possible with Provider instead of RiverPod :)

Comment: If you're learning brand new, ignore provider.  The author has moved on to riverpod.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! One more question, I know this would sound weird cuz I've never learned design patterns but my teammate structured this project based on MVVM, but according to your response do you think it's based on MVC?

Comment: I prefer the simplicity of thinking of view, model, and controller, even though in flutter using riverpod, the controller is somewhat straddling view and model.